# How do you display the "file window" on the left of Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio, and I am using VS 2008. I would like to know how to display the window that is usually on the left side. It contains a kind of organization tree, with the project name, as well as "header files," "resource files," etc, and folders which contain all of your files. You can right click on these folders to create new files. It is just a simple window that helps me keep track of what files I have in the project, and I closed out of it and can't figure out how to open it back up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution explorer can be enabled by going to View -> Solution Explorer.

Comment: THANKS MAN haha I don't know how I missed that. I tried every other option in the view menu ._.

Comment: No problem! :) Don't forget to accept this as the answer by checking the checkbox to the left.